# How to take factors of probability in to account?

Tags: probability

I do not know if my question is fully put in the right way . I am really new in probability and I am just starting from the zero point .so any arguments I take are based on logic and I am not fully sure if they are valid. 
So the Question is :
Assuming there is a country where all carmanfactures produce only red cars . There are 10 carmanfactures in the city . 70% of the people have their cars from john .Jack has bought a car . 
What is the probability that his car is from John? 
My argument: I think it is 70%  since the ratio of the people at a time is actually the probability. I think also that 70% represent the probability as a result , meaning that  time must have passed in order for him to reach 70% . it also mean that there have been factors which increased his probability.  I think that the his starting value at time=0 was 10% and then it increased . 
My Questions
-What does the 10% value represent if i am wrong?
-what is the probability if I am wrong
-Is there is a function which take factors into account ? for example  ; his cars are cheap,  good and stable.

Comment: The $10\%$ represents precisely what you stated: It is *what you think*. Sometimes estimates are appropriate (especially in real life), but I don't see why you need to make such an observation/guess here - you already have the correct answer of $70\%$. Usually in elementary math problems, you're only to use the assumptions given - no need to do any world-building. :)

Comment: Ok but how can I take take factors of people buying his car into account ?  . I know that this factors increased the probability from 10% to 70% ? If you have any source i can rely onto to understand such concepts.

Comment: You have to make a model with some assumptions; that is scientific work. However, before trying that, you should have a good grasp of a lot of statistics and probability.

Comment: Ok thank you for the helpful information :)